Alternative method to generate a date in Google Sheets
I am looking for an alternative method to generate a date in Google Sheets when a checkbox is ticked, as using a formula slows down the sheet. Furthermore, using an App Script also slows down the sheet. I need an alternative to both the formula and App Script that won't slow down the sheet.
I have tried an app script and formula that are causing the sheet to slow down significantly.

use LAMBDA
=LAMBDA(x; x)(IF(A1; NOW(); ))

where A1 is your checkbox
